# Cant update MySQL DateTime field as I sent in loopback.io

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs

I am trying to update MySQL `DateTime` field with "2015-07-29 **13**:23:54".
Loopback updates like "2015-07-29 **10**:23:54".

How can I write datetime filed to db exactly as I sent?

Note: I tried datasource timezone option `local` and `utc`. It does not matters.

Answer (score 4):

After loopback 3.0 there is an option (it is not documented) called `legacyUtcDateProcessing`. If you set this parameter to `false` there is no problem about dates...

Comment: I know this is old but still helps :)

Comment: What does setting this property to false do behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by changing the core file which is not a best practice 
but still you can  try until this bug is fixed by loopback-connector-mysql

To make it work
Change function "dateToMysql()" located at ***/var/www/yourproject/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js***

**From**

```
function dateToMysql(val) {
  return val.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    fillZeros(val.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    fillZeros(val.getUTCDate()) + ' ' +
    fillZeros(val.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
    fillZeros(val.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
    fillZeros(val.getUTCSeconds());

  function fillZeros(v) {
    return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
  }
}
```

**To**

```
function dateToMysql(val) {
  return val.getFullYear() + '-' +
    fillZeros(val.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
    fillZeros(val.getDate()) + ' ' +
    fillZeros(val.getHours()) + ':' +
    fillZeros(val.getMinutes()) + ':' +
    fillZeros(val.getSeconds());

  function fillZeros(v) {
    return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
  }
}
```